# ggplot problematic aesthetic(s): y = n

Tags: r, ggplot2, group-by, count

**Trying to plot this graph:** to count number of occurances by day of the week and hour of the day
[image]

**Using this code:**

```
p2 <- train %>%
  mutate(hpick = hour(pickup_datetime),
         wday = factor(wday(pickup_datetime, label = TRUE))) %>%
  group_by(hpick, wday) %>%
  count() %>%
  ggplot(aes(hpick, n, color = wday)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.5) +
  labs(x = "Hour of the day", y = "count")
```

**I get this error:**

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in `f()`:
! Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): y = n. 
Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
>
```

The first 5 lines of code, I can't include the whole dataset:

```
structure(list(passenger_count = c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), pickup_longitude = c(-73.9975814819336, -73.934700012207, -74.004768371582, -74.004623413086, -73.870834350586), pickup_latitude = c(40.7224349975586, 40.7448310852051, 40.7417182922363, 40.7240180969238, 40.7737808227539),pickup_datetime = structure(c(1426359929, 1426596943, 1426378969, 1426719734, 1426420427), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dropoff_datetime = structure(c(1426360739, 1426597375, 1426380520, 1426719849, 1426422210), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), row.names = c(7L, 8L, 9L, 17L, 24L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am not sure how to fix this error, someone please help.

Comment: Your code works fine for me with some simulated data

Comment: Me too. I think you just need to restart your R session, do `library(tidyverse)`, and run your code again.

Comment: please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: @AllanCameron I've done the suggested, it is still not working...

Comment: @Katie can you edit your question to include your data? Copy and paste the output of `dput(train)` into your question - thanks

Comment: what does the data look like immediately after  count()

Comment: @AllanCameron done! Unfortunately had to cut it to the first 5 rows, and included only the most important columns, it does not let me share everything.

Comment: What version of R are you using?

Comment: @RichardTelford R 4.2.0, i believe it's the latest one :c

Comment: @Katie currently your times are in character format. Have you remembered to `mutate` these to `as.POSIXct`? I still don't get your error using the vode and data supplied

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes, when converted to POSIXct, I keep getting the same error. Very strange...

Comment: I get your error if I comment out the `count()` line. What do you see when you run only to here? `train %>% mutate(hpick = hour(pickup_datetime),
         wday = factor(wday(pickup_datetime, label = TRUE))) %>%
  group_by(hpick, wday) %>% count()`

Comment: do you get the same error with these simulated data `k <- 100;
train <- tibble(pickup_datetime = rep(lubridate::now(), k)) |> 
  mutate(pickup_datetime = pickup_datetime + runif(k, 0, 1000000))`

Comment: @Carl, if i run it until count(), it just starts counting the rows

Comment: @RichardTelford, I get the same error. It must be something with my R... Already restarted my laptop, etc. but it still keeps doing this.

Comment: do you have any other packges loaded? If you type count it should tell you that it is in dpyr. There is also a count in plyr and you may have a conflict

Comment: @RichardTelford, you are right! thank you so much! there was a conflict between my packages and now it finally worked!! thanks everyone for helping!

Comment: The conflicted package is useful for preventing conflicts.